# Find Command with multiple file extensions

Tags: linux, shell, unix, find

I'm looking through many sub directories and finding all the files ending in .JPG .jpg and .png and copying them to a separate directory, however just now its only finding .JPG

Could someone explain what i'm doing wrong?

```
find /root/TEST/Images -name  '*.png' -o  -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.JPG' -exec cp -t /root/TEST/CopiedImages {} +
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to group the `-o` conditions because `-a`, the implied AND between the last `-name '*.JPG'` and `-exec` has [higher precedence](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Combining-Primaries-With-Operators):

```
find /root/TEST/Images \( -name  '*.png' -o  -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.JPG' \) -exec cp -t /root/TEST/CopiedImages {} +
```

Grouping is done with parentheses, but they have to be escaped (or quoted) due to their special meaning is shell.

Unrelated to this, you can shorten the overall expression by combining filters for `jpg` and `JPG` with the case-insensitive `-iname` (as noted in comments):

```
find /root/TEST/Images \( -name  '*.png' -o  -iname '*.jpg' \) -exec cp -t /root/TEST/CopiedImages {} +
```

Comment: "line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `(' " is the error i'm getting when using that line of code

Comment: Can you try with quoted parens instead, `'('` and `')'`?

Comment: Still getting an error:                                                                                  
find: paths must precede expression:  )
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]

Comment: Are you using this in a script? Have to copy/pasted the line exactly, or modified your line? It should work as it' written.

Comment: Don't know what i was doing wrong there. Works fine now. Thanks!

Comment: You can use `-iname jpg` for case insensitivity.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, added. Thanks!

Comment: @tink, why do you think `+` has to be escaped?

Comment: fair question; I guess because one had to escape the ; as a terminator for -exec. But of course + has no special meaning to the shell ... so ignore my previous comment :D